# One of threads rewrites console input in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, console-application

I have a problem with console app with threading. In first thread i have a function, which write symbol "x" into output. In second thread i have function, which waiting for users input. (Symbol "x" is just random choice for this question).

For ex.

Thread 1:

```
    while True:
        print "x"
        time.sleep(1)
```

Thread 2:

```
    input = null
    while input != "EXIT":
        input = raw_input()
        print input
```

But when i write text for thread 2 to console, my input text (for ex. HELLO) is rewroted.

```
    x
    x
    HELx
    LOx
    x
    x[enter pressed here]

    HELLO
    x
    x
```

Is any way how can i prevent rewriting my input text by symbol "x"?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you want from your program.  What do you want the console output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a console, standard output (produced by the running program(s)) and standard input (produced by your keypresses) are both sent to screen, so they may end up all mixed.

Here your thread 1 writes 1 `x` by line every second, so if your take more than 1 second to type `HELLO` then that will produce the in-console output that you submitted.

If you want to avoid that, a few non-exhaustive suggestions:

- temporarily interrupt thread1 output when a keypress is detected
- use a library such as ncurses to create separates zones for your program output and the user input
- just suppress thread1 input, or send it to a file instead.

Comment: Thanks. I try ncurses.